Local Storage breaks code when injecting the JavaScript to an Android WebView
I have this html which i add to the webview.loadData():
@ReactProp(name = "message")
public void setWebviewHtml(LinearLayout view, String html) {
  if(! this.cacheData) {
    Toast.makeText(reactContext, "sfbsfbsfb: " + this.cacheData + " : " + messageId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    String uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");
    uniqueId = "APPJS" + uniqueId;
    // Toast.makeText(reactContext, "uniqueId: " + uniqueId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'><title>HTML5 Boilerplate</title><script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js' integrity='sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==' crossorigin='anonymous' referrerpolicy='no-referrer'></script></head><body style='margin:0;padding:0;word-wrap:break-word;'>" + html + "</body></html>";

    // oast.makeText(reactContext, "html: " + html, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    html += "<script>\n";
    html += "localStorage.setItem('" + messageId + "', '" + html + "');\n"; // This line breaks the code and does not render anything
    html += "$(document).ready(function() {\n";
    html += "   javascript:" + uniqueId + ".ResizeWebView($(document).height());\n";
    html += "});\n";
    html += "</script>\n";
    layout.setWebviewHtml(html, uniqueId);
  }
}

And my setWebviewHtml() is:
public void setWebviewHtml(String html, String uniqueId) {
  // Toast.makeText(context, "html2: " + html, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  webView.loadData(html, "text/html", "UTF-8");
  webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
  webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JSInterface(webView, context, this), uniqueId);
  webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
  webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
  // webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
  webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
}

When I remove that line:
html += "localStorage.setItem('" + messageId + "', '" + html + "');\n";

The WebView renders but with the LocalStorage code the app stops rendering.

Do you get any error in the console while debugging webview?

no no errors, i tried putting a try catch around the localstorage.setitem but did not pull in errors out

I meant this method of debugging https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Debugging.md#android--chrome

Have you tried extracting the local storage data to a method in JS and calling it from your native layer (via a communication bridge)?
